# What is the document parameter used for in the Dojo domConstruct.toDom function?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Dojo has a domConstruct.toDom method used to create DOM.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-construct.html#id17

This takes two parameters:

- The fragment of HTML to be converted into a node
- An optional document to use when creating DOM nodes, defaults to dojo/_base/window::doc if not specified.

What is the purpose of the document parameter and can you give me an example of how or when I would use it? All the examples I have found only use the HTML fragment parameter on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create DOM elements in raw Javascript, you need to use the methods of a [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) object (You can check this in the [source](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/dom-construct.js) for toDom)

```
var e = document.createElement('div');

var df = createDocumentFragment();
```

Most of the time, the only document that matters is the main document associated with your current page so you will almost never have to use a different document and pass that optional parameter to toDom.

Honestly, I'm having a hard time coming up with a use case for that optional parameter. The only examples I can think of is if you want to create HTML for another window you control, probably a popup or iframe. Other than that, a common reason to have multiple documents if if you are creating XML documents for AJAX requests but I think toDom is intended for HTML only so this is not what you are looking for.